# VBA losing links

Tags: excel, vba

Manual - Select range, execute Sub

How it works - Sub saves all non-blank cells to finalArray that is ultimately displayed in the selected range

What's the problem - if range contains cells with hyperlinks created via insert-hyperlink, the hyperlinks disappear.

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()
'i,j - counters,  k - offset

Dim finalArray() As Variant
ReDim finalArray(Selection.Rows.Count, 1)
k = 1

For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    If Selection(i, 1) <> "" Then
    finalArray(k, 1) = Selection(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Selection.Clear

For i = 1 To k
    Selection(i, 1).Value = finalArray(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What you want to do is remove blank cells, right?

Comment: Once you have captured the range, what is it that you want to do with it? just to capture the hyperlink for.. lets say **A2** on a sheet, you could just do this: `oWS.Range("A2").Hyperlinks(oWS.Range("A2").Hyperlinks.Count).Name` (where `oWS` is the sheet with your original range). Some tips: 1. It's not advisable to use things like `Selection`. Try and qualify your range. 2. you don't need the **`k`** counter. `finalArray` is an array. You can just use `LBound` or `UBound`. 3. If you are switching off things like `ScreenUpdating`, don't forget to turn them back on

Comment: @Zac ScreenUpdating - what if I leave them as False? Everything seems to work correctly

Comment: **ScreenUpdating** as off doesn't affect how your code works. All it does is not show you on the screen what is happening with your visible workbook. You can leave it off but I have seen a few question because the user was complaining that code run but they can't see anything happening because they forget to turn things back on. Good practice is to switch everything back on at the end of your macro

Answer (score 0):

This Code will loops through each cell in the selected range, checks if the cell has a hyperlink then temporarily grab and store the address that it’s pointing to re-apply the hyperlink

```
Option Explicit

Sub fixHyperlinks()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim address As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rng In Selection
        If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            address = rng.Hyperlinks(rng.Hyperlinks.Count).address  

            rng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, _
                               address:=address  
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After you run this code, you should be able to set in your array the range without losing your links.

**Conclusion :** Run this code before you run your macro.

Comment: Not sure how this works, the issue is that in storing in an array the hyperlink is lost. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SJR I think that the issue is due to someting like [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214328/hyperlinks-are-removed-or-invalid-after-you-sort-cells-that-contain-th) So to handle it we need to fix hyperlink before.

Comment: Having done a quick test I think the problem is that the array just stores the text, not the actual link but we shall see what OP says.

Comment: @SJR So maybe the other way is to convert the text to link. Lets wait for his **feedbacks**

Comment: Well, I think that the best way would be to store values together with hyperlinks. Something like 2-dimensional array?

Comment: @SJR  you're right - the finalArray consists only of values, without links

Comment: @SJR Can I have example of link by adding it to your post ? I got an idea

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a way around the issue after lurking through internet and trying to save links in another array (fails). It works only if the value in the cell is the same as name of a sheet, yet it solves my issue so far.

```
Sub CreateLinks()
'i - counter, the title as i=1 is omitted. Code uses value stored in cell to 
 'transform it into a link. 
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
    If Selection(i) <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Selection(i), _
                               address:="#'" & CStr(Selection(i)) & "'!A1", _
                               TextToDisplay:=CStr(Selection(i))
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```